# What benefits do I gain by building terminals?

Tags: fallout-4

The terminals say that I can access additional options when paired with other objects, but what kind of options does this mean?

Is it worth investing the time and resources into terminals in your settlement?

Comment: From what I've seen, there are timed switches that allow you to configure the delay using a terminal.

Comment: This is a good question.  I attached a terminal to a few things to see what happens and all I get is a please wait window.

Comment: If you watched the E3 demo, they showed that you can also toggle/set the display of various lights as well (changing color/pattern and whatnot)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Terminals allow you to control all switches, lightboxes and turrets connected to the terminal. Since the terminal is connected to your power, essentially this is any of the above connected to the same power grid.

[image: terminal turret options]

[image: lots of wires]

[image: pixel heart]

Comment: Well isn't that the cutest post apocalyptic heart you've ever seen!?